# Expiration Timer Job only does half the job

Tags: document-library, timer-jobs, records-management, expiration

I have been testing expiration policies on a library.

I put in about 2 dozen documents and then run the expiration timer job in CA.

What I notice is that only half of the documents get processed.

I then run the timer job again and the other half get processed. Is this normal behaviour? Or is there some not so obvious configuration that needs to be set so the timer job has enough juice to finish the job?

To my mind 2 dozen documents doesn't sound like much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to include the execution time of your timer job. This might be affecting things. You are saying that it is just 2 dozens of document but those are still data that maybe cannot be process by the minimum time of 5 minutes. It is safer i think to do it once a day for one hour else you can just do it every hour with 5 minutes execution time besides the remaining document would still be processed on the next run.

Comment: Sorry I must be missing something here (I'm still new to Sharepoint). You seem to be suggesting that timer jobs only run for a default of 5 minutes. Is there a way to make it run for longer? Is this done in the job definition or is there another way?

Comment: Yes there is a way, Go to your central Admin, Click Monitoring. Click Timer Job Definitions, Look for your time job and click it, there you can find the timing of your timer job you can set that hourly to run on 10 minutes but still 5 minutes is for me the best timing for an hourly interval running of the Job since it is consuming resources while its running.